# in java, why do closured variables need to be declared final?

Tags: java, jvm, closures, language-design

```
final Object o;

List l = new ArrayList(){{
    // closure over o, in lexical scope
    this.add(o);
}};
```

why must `o` be declared final? why don't other JVM languages with mutable vars have this requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not JVM-deep, it all happens at syntactic-sugar level. The reason is that exporting a non-final var via a closure makes it vulnerable to datarace issues and, since Java was designed to be a "blue-collar" language, such a surprising change in the behavior of an otherwise tame and safe local var was deemed way too "advanced".

Comment: IMHO quite a strange design decision, given that the _fields_ of a final ref to a class instance may be changed at any time.

Comment: @DustinGetz It happens when several threads contend for the same var -- at least one reading and one writing it.

Comment: @Vlad The class being final really has nothing to do with this. The fields are generally known and accepted to be subject to dataraces.

Comment: @Marko: that is exactly my point. The problem is solved only on one level, giving false feeling of safety. (I've corrected "final class" -> "final ref".)

Comment: @Vlad But shared fields are bread-and-butter of any imaginable data-sharing scenario between threads! If you didn't have that issue, the language would have no need for `synchronized` and `volatile` costructs.

Comment: @Marko: This is perfectly clear, the only thing which is not clear is the one the OP asked: why then is it needed to have the closed-by references unmodifiable, provided that their fields are anyway modifiable! The point is that the discussed precaution is worth not very much. Right?

Comment: BTW @Vlad `final` refs are immune to dataraces.

Comment: @Vlad then again we're not talking about the contents of a local var. In Java, as it looks today, there can **never ever** come to a datarace on the contents of a local var.

Comment: @Marko: I cannot agree with you. Imagine that you have a final ref, and you are calling `hashCode` on it -- is it still thread-safe? :-)

Comment: @Vlad What does thread-safey of a `hashCode` call have to do with the thread-safety of a local var, or a final ref? If the call only involves the read of a final fields, then it's thread-safe. If not, well then you are involving non-final fields!

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard to deduce logically why it has to be `final`.

In Java, when a local variable is captured into an anonymous class, it is copied by value. The reason for this is that the object may live longer than the current function call (e.g. it may be returned, etc.), but local variables only live as long as the current function call. So it is not possible to simply "reference" the variable because it may not exist by then. Some languages like Python, Ruby, JavaScript, do allow you to reference variables after the scope is gone, by keeping a reference to the environment in the heap or something. But this is hard to do with the JVM because local variables are allocated on the function's stack frame, which is destroyed when the function call is done.

Now, since it is copied, there are two copies of the variable (and more, if there are more closures capturing this variable). If they were assignable, then you can change one of them without changing the other. For example, hypothetically:

```
Object o;

Object x = new Object(){
    public String toString() {
        return o.toString();
    }
};
o = somethingElse;
System.out.println(x.toString()); // prints the original object, not the re-assigned one
                                  // even though "o" now refers to the re-assigned one
```

Since there is only one `o` variable in the scope, you would expect them to to refer to the same thing. In the example above, after you assign to `o`, you would expect a later access of `o` from the object to refer to the new value; but it doesn't. This would be surprising and unexpected to the programmer, and violates the principle that uses of the same variable refer to the same thing.

So to avoid this surprise, they mandate that you cannot assign to it anywhere; i.e. it has to be `final`.

Now, of course, you can still initialize the `final` variable from a non-`final` variable. And inside the closure, you can still assign the `final` variable to something else non-`final`.

```
Object a; // non-final
final Object o = a;

Object x = new Object(){
    Object m = o; // non-final
    public String toString() {
        return ,.toString();
    }
};
```

But then this is all good since you are explicitly using different variables, so there is no surprise about what it does.

Comment: "But this is hard to do with the JVM because local variables are allocated on the function's stack frame, which is destroyed when the function call is done." wait, what? if that is the case, java could have destructors.

Comment: @DustinGetz: I am talking about variables. You are confusing it with objects. Objects can NEVER be values in Java. Values are primitives and references, and do not have anything to do with destructors.