# Scope of override function parameters

Tags: java, scope

I program on Android Studio in Java, and I wonder which variable I have the right to access.
For instance:

```
public class Myclass {
    public Object var1;

    public fct(Object var2) {

        dataBaseReference.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {

            @overrride
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(@NonNull MutableData currentData) {
                //here why I can access var1 but not var2
                //and how can I access var2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a complete, compilable;e example which illustrates your question.

Comment: it works with public fct(**final** Object var2)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626132/in-java-why-do-closured-variables-need-to-be-declared-final

Comment: thanks, in addition there is https://data-flair.training/blogs/java-closure/

Comment: Do you know why i can acces to var1?